# Cropping shapefiles in a loop in R

Tags: r, gis

I have an extensive number of `shapefiles`, all of various sizes as they represent different species distributions. I am trying to loop through all of these `shapefiles` and crop other raster files (BioClim variables) by these `shapefiles`. It seems that my problem arises due to the `shapefiles` themselves. I have tried stacking and that does not work. Given my lack of experience working with `shapefiles` in a loop, can anyone provide insight into why the subset of code provided below will not work?

```
library(raster)
library (sp)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library (raster)
library (maps)
library (mapproj)
library(sp)
library(maptools)

raster("alt.bil") -> alt
raster("bio_1.bil") -> bio1

shape.files=list.files(path="PathToFolderWithShapefiles", pattern="*.shp", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)


lapply(shape.files, function(x){
    masking= altc = crop(alt, shape.files)
    bio1 = crop(bio1, shape.files)
setwd("/Volumes/LaCie/LoopTestOutput")
writeRaster(altc, filename="alt.asc", bylayer=T, overwrite=FALSE)
writeRaster(bio1, filename="bio1.asc", bylayer=T, overwrite=FALSE)
})
```

Below is a set of code that works for a single, specific, shapefile. I would essentially like to loop the cropping function across all shapefiles within a folder and output the cropped raster file.

```
require(raster)
library (sp)
install.packages('rgeos',repos="http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin")
install.packages('rgdal',repos="http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin")
library (raster)
library (maps)
library (mapproj)
library(sp)
library(maptools)

setwd("PathToGlobalRasterLayers")

raster("alt.bil") -> alt
raster("bio_1.bil") -> bio1

setwd("PathTofolderContainingSpeciesDelimitedShapefiles")#all files necessary for working with shapefiles are here, .shp, .dbf, etc.#
mask <- readShapeSpatial("ReadInSpeciesDelimitedShapefile")

altc = crop(alt, mask)
bio1 = crop(bio1, mask)


setwd("OutputFolderForCroppedFiles")

writeRaster(altc, filename="alt.asc", bylayer=T, overwrite=TRUE)
writeRaster(bio1, filename="bio1.asc", bylayer=T, overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: use `x` instead of `shape.files` (which is the list) in your function ?

Comment: Tensibai, thank you for your quick response! I changed the function to reflect `x` rather than `shape.files`, but I received the following error...`Error in .local(x, y, ...) : Cannot get an Extent object from argument y`....which is why I think this problem has something to do with the fact that I am looping shapefiles specifically

Comment: When I have problems with complex lapply functions, I rewrite them as old-style for-loops, and then work through them line-by-line to ensure every step is working. You might try that, and you might try updating your question with a simple reproducible example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Ben! I will give for-loop writing a shot!

Answer (score 0):

In your first block of code, it seems that you forgot to run
`masking = readShapeSpatial(x)`.

Also, do not use `setwd()`, just put the path in the `filename=` argument. This will make your code more explicit and readable.